# Is there a Church Tradition that the original Apostles were ever baptized?

Tags: baptism, tradition, apostles

I had been thinking about this, but since it isn't ever mentioned in the Bible, is there any teaching that says the original disciples and apostles were ever baptized?

Comment: Andrew, Simon, Philip, Nathanael (and. by implication, John) were disciples of John the Baptist, first, and would have been baptised by him (see John 1:35-51).

Comment: It's reasonable to assume they were baptised, but it's probably also indicative that the scriptures don't say so.

Comment: And Jesus saved Peter from another baptism. Although that wasn't what he'd call it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is there a Church Tradition that the original Apostles were ever baptized?**

Many churches hold that the Apostles were indeed baptized.

The Scriptures in themselves do not reveal anything about this. But, it makes logical sense that they were in fact baptized.

St Thomas in his [***Summa theologiae*** III, q. 72, a. 6, ad. 2](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/4072.htm) quotes St. Augustine and affirms that the Apostles were baptized.

> As Augustine says (Ep. cclxv), from our Lord's words, "'He that is washed, needeth not but to wash his feet' (John 13:10), we gather that Peter and Christ's other disciples had been baptized, either with John's Baptism, as some think; or with Christ's, which is more credible. For He did not refuse to administer Baptism, so as to have servants by whom to baptize others."

We really do not know when the Apostles were actually baptized.

As a Catholic, I imagine it would have to be before the **Last Supper**. The sacrament of baptism opens the door to the possibility of other sacraments including ordination which we believe occurred at the **Last Supper**.

> There is nothing in the Scriptures that describes the apostles having been baptized by Jesus — but of course the Gospels provide only the broad outlines of the public life of Christ and not every detail.
>
> I think that it would be safe to assume that Jesus did baptize the Twelve. Just before his ascension, Jesus makes it clear that baptism is a basic part of becoming his disciple; in the final words of Matthew’s Gospel, Jesus commissions the apostles to “go, therefore, and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit, teaching them to observe all that I have commanded you.”
>
> In John’s Gospel (3:22), we read that, “after this, Jesus and his disciples went into the region of Judea, where he spent some time with them baptizing.” So I take it as a logical conclusion that Jesus had first baptized his own apostles. - [Were the apostles baptized?](https://catholicreview.org/were-the-apostles-baptized-what-should-a-homily-be-about/)